# How do I create the local website files from this piece of code?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I recently decided to start getting back into HTML & CSS & a bit of JS..
I just need to get some revision since I used to do it back in the day.

And I found this code snipped online to this project that seemed fun to play around with but for some reason it wont work.

Source code HTML:

```
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2:900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<div id="wrapper">

        <div id="wheel">
            <div id="inner-wheel">
                <div class="sec"><span class="fa fa-bell-o"></span></div>
                <div class="sec"><span class="fa fa-comment-o"></span></div>
                <div class="sec"><span class="fa fa-smile-o"></span></div>
                <div class="sec"><span class="fa fa-heart-o"></span></div>
                <div class="sec"><span class="fa fa-star-o"></span></div>
                <div class="sec"><span class="fa fa-lightbulb-o"></span></div>
            </div>       

            <div id="spin">
                <div id="inner-spin"></div>
            </div>

            <div id="shine"></div>
        </div>


        <div id="txt"></div>
  </div>
```

Source code CSS:

```
*{  margin:0;   padding:0; }

body{
    background:#eaeaea;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:18px;
    font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
}

a{
    color:#34495e;  
}




/*WRAPPER*/
#wrapper{ 
    margin: 40px auto 0;    
    width:266px; 
    position:relative;
}

#txt{
    color:#eaeaea;  
}


/*WHEEL*/
#wheel{
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    border-radius:50%;  
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:8px solid #fff;
    box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0px 0px 10px, rgba(0,0,0,0.05) 0px 3px 0px;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}

#wheel:before{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    border:4px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    width:242px;
    height:242px;
    border-radius:50%;
    z-index:1000;   
}

#inner-wheel{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;

    -webkit-transition: all 6s cubic-bezier(0,.99,.44,.99);
    -moz-transition:    all 6 cubic-bezier(0,.99,.44,.99);
    -o-transition:      all 6s cubic-bezier(0,.99,.44,.99);
    -ms-transition:     all 6s cubic-bezier(0,.99,.44,.99);
    transition:         all 6s cubic-bezier(0,.99,.44,.99); 
}

#wheel div.sec{
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 130px 75px 0;
    border-color: #19c transparent;
    transform-origin: 75px 129px;
    left:50px;
    top:-4px;   
    opacity:1;
}

#wheel div.sec:nth-child(1){
    transform: rotate(60deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(60deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(60deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(60deg);
    border-color: #16a085 transparent;  
}
#wheel div.sec:nth-child(2){
    transform: rotate(120deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(120deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(120deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(120deg);
    border-color: #2980b9 transparent;  
}
#wheel div.sec:nth-child(3){
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    border-color: #34495e transparent;  
}
#wheel div.sec:nth-child(4){
    transform: rotate(240deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(240deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(240deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(240deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(240deg);
    border-color: #f39c12 transparent;  
}
#wheel div.sec:nth-child(5){
    transform: rotate(300deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(300deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(300deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(300deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(300deg);
    border-color: #d35400 transparent;  
}
#wheel div.sec:nth-child(6){
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    border-color: #c0392b transparent;  
}


#wheel div.sec .fa{
    margin-top: -100px;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10000000;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size:36px;
    margin-left:-15px;

    text-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0px -1px 0px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 1px 0px;
}




#spin{
    width:68px;
    height:68px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin:-34px 0 0 -34px;
    border-radius:50%;
    box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0px 3px 0px;
    z-index:1000;
    background:#fff;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;

  -webkit-user-select: none; 
  -moz-user-select: none;    
  -ms-user-select: none;     
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;   
}


#spin:after{
    content:"SPIN"; 
    text-align:center;
    line-height:68px;
    color:#CCC;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 0 #fff, 0 -2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3) ;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100000;
    width:68px;
    height:68px;
    display:block;
}

#spin:before{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 20px 28px 20px;
    border-color: transparent transparent #ffffff transparent;
    top:-12px;
    left:14px;
}

#inner-spin{
    width:54px;
    height:54px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin:-27px 0 0 -27px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background:red;
    z-index:999;
    box-shadow:rgba(255,255,255,1) 0px -2px 0px inset, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0px 2px 0px inset,  rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 0px 0px 5px ;

    background: rgb(255,255,255); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(234,234,234,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(234,234,234,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(234,234,234,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(234,234,234,1) 100%); /* Opera 12+ */
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(234,234,234,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(234,234,234,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#eaeaea',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */    
}

#spin:active #inner-spin{
    box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 0px 0px 5px inset;
}

#spin:active:after{
    font-size:15px; 
}



#shine{
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.99) 1%, rgba(255,255,255,0.91) 9%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(1%,rgba(255,255,255,0.99)), color-stop(9%,rgba(255,255,255,0.91)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.99) 1%,rgba(255,255,255,0.91) 9%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.99) 1%,rgba(255,255,255,0.91) 9%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Opera 12+ */
background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.99) 1%,rgba(255,255,255,0.91) 9%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.99) 1%,rgba(255,255,255,0.91) 9%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */


opacity:0.1;

}



/*ANIMATION*/
@-webkit-keyframes hh {
  0%, 100%{
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  50%{
    transform: rotate(7deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(7deg);
  }
}

@keyframes hh {
   0%, 100%{
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  50%{
    transform: rotate(7deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(7deg);
  }
}

.spin {
  -webkit-animation: hh 0.1s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: hh 0.1s;
}
```

Source Code JS:

```
//set default degree (360*5)
var degree = 1800;
//number of clicks = 0
var clicks = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){

    /*WHEEL SPIN FUNCTION*/
    $('#spin').click(function(){

        //add 1 every click
        clicks ++;

        /*multiply the degree by number of clicks
      generate random number between 1 - 360, 
    then add to the new degree*/
        var newDegree = degree*clicks;
        var extraDegree = Math.floor(Math.random() * (360 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
        totalDegree = newDegree+extraDegree;

        /*let's make the spin btn to tilt every
        time the edge of the section hits 
        the indicator*/
        $('#wheel .sec').each(function(){
            var t = $(this);
            var noY = 0;

            var c = 0;
            var n = 700;    
            var interval = setInterval(function () {
                c++;                
                if (c === n) { 
                    clearInterval(interval);                
                }   

                var aoY = t.offset().top;
                $("#txt").html(aoY);
                console.log(aoY);

                /*23.7 is the minumum offset number that 
                each section can get, in a 30 angle degree.
                So, if the offset reaches 23.7, then we know
                that it has a 30 degree angle and therefore, 
                exactly aligned with the spin btn*/
                if(aoY < 23.89){
                    console.log('<<<<<<<<');
                    $('#spin').addClass('spin');
                    setTimeout(function () { 
                        $('#spin').removeClass('spin');
                    }, 100);    
                }
            }, 10);

            $('#inner-wheel').css({
                'transform' : 'rotate(' + totalDegree + 'deg)'          
            });

            noY = t.offset().top;

        });
    });



});//DOCUMENT READY
```

I tried creating a `index.html` a `css.css` and a `js.js` and adding all the code inside of them but didn't work.

This is what I get:

[image: website]

[This is what the website looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IN0h.png)

I'm pretty sure I need to change the html paths but I cant really get it to work.

What have I been doing wrong?

Comment: How are we to guess what you might have done wrong without any code?

Comment: js.js... Amazing names, very descriptive

Comment: Your question is baseless. What have you tried and where is the code?

Comment: I understand I made a big misstake when not adding the code but its added now.

Comment: You have added code but what is it that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to create a local website which runs from the desktop. 
So when you open the index.html it shows the same thign as the code would on here https://codepen.io/bsngr/pen/ezZjpB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put your entire HTML code in 'body' tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Our Page</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <!--Put you html code here-->

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Include any JavaScript before your main script(which is `js.js` and is alredy icluded here). And your CSS files in the 'head' tag.

Comment: That made the wheen appear! Now I just need to make it spin!

Comment: make sure that all files which are index.html ; css.css ; js.js are in same folder

Comment: Yeah they are, still the same result.

Comment: now I added juery cdn in my answer. I think it would work.

Comment: do you see it. the lscript above your js.js script

Comment: Now the website is just white for some reason.

Comment: Fixed it! Thank you!